# Solr/Lucene spellcheck suggestions based on multiple fields

Tags: lucene, solr, spell-checking

I have a database with Vendor's information: name and address (address, city, zip and country fields). I need to search this database and return some vendors. On the search box, the user could type anything: name of the vendor, part of the address, city, zip,... And, if I can't find any results, I need to implement a google like "Did you mean" feature to give a suggestion to the user.

I thought about using Solr/Lucene to do it. I've installed Solr, exported the information I need using CSV file and created the indexes based on this file. Now I am able to get suggestions from a Solr field using solr.SpellCheckComponent. The thing is my suggestion is based in a single field and need it to get information from address, city, zip, country and name fields.

On solr config file I have something like this:

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
<str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>

<lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">default</str>
    <str name="field">name</str>
    <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">spellchecker</str>
</lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count>1</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

I can run queries like:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/spell?q=some_company_name&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.collate=true&spellcheck.build=true
```

Does anyone know how to change my config file in order to have suggestions from multiple fields?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use copyfield for this in schema.xml.`<copyField source="*" dest="contentSpell"/>` will copy all the fields to contentSpell.

Then change `<str name="field">name</str>` to `<str name="field">contentSpell</str>` en you will get suggestions from all fields.

Answer (score 7):

In order to configure Solr spellcheck to use words from several fields you should:

1. Declare a new field.  The New field declaration should use the properties type="textSpell" and multiValued="true". For example: `<field name="didYouMean" type="textSpell" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>`.
2. Copy all the fields, of which their words should be part of the spellcheck index, into the new field.  For example: `<copyField source="field1" dest="didYouMean"/>
   <copyField source="field2" dest="didYouMean"/>`.
3. Configure Solr to use the new field. Do it by set the field name to use your spellcheck field name. For example: `<str name="field">didYouMean</str>`.

For more and detailed information visit [Solr spellcheck compound from several fields](http://www.rndblog.com/solr-spellcheck-compound-from-several-fields/)